# Which test to use for a simple multiple-choice question?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I asked 200 people a multiple-choice question with four possible answer options and received the following responses:

Option A: 2
Option B: 148
Option C: 50
Option D: 0

Each respondent could select only one option. What's the correct statistical test to use to show that these responses weren't random?

(My first thought was to carry out a binomial test for each option, but that would of course make the responses for Option C appear random.)

Comment: @ttnphns In my experience, "multiple choice" is generally used to mean "selecting only one of the available options"; on the other hand, "multiple response" is used in a similar type of question but where people are allowed to select more than one response. ([This also seems to be the interpretation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_choice), by the way.)

Comment: What Silverfish said. "Multiple choice" means there's more than one option to choose from. "Multiple response" means more than one option can be selected. The case in point is multiple choice, single response.

Comment: What does "random" mean here? If you want to test a hypothesis of equal frequencies, try a chi-square test. Experience teaches that such unequal frequencies certainly signal a very, very distinct preference but you can go through the motions. A Pearson chi-square gives me a P-value of the order of $10^{-62}$ and a likelihood ratio chi-square a P-value that is even smaller, if you need to undermine any sceptics.

Comment: @Nick Cox. Many thanks for your reply (and for correcting my inept typos). The purpose here is to show it's unlikely that respondents were selecting the options randomly - with a pin, if you like. Just one further question about this. Excel's CHITEST function is giving me 3.63168E-62 rather than 10E-62 (which I presume is equivalent to the answer you've given). Does this imply that I've done something wrong?

Comment: I said "of the order of" because I don't believe one can or should try to interpret more finely with such minute P-values. Of the order of $10^{-62}$ means 1e-62 not 10 times that! But for the record `chitesti` in Stata yields 3.63167785998e-62 which should reassure you. It doesn't print that, but the result is accessible. That doesn't mean that the P-value is exact to so many significant figures, just that Stata and Excel are evidently using similar code.

Comment: @Nick Cox. Thanks again, and despite my promise, here's another question about this. Given that the P-value was always going to be minute, is it even worth commenting on? The context is experimental philosophy, the closest established discipline to which would be social science. (My training is in philosophy rather than science, so I'm very much a newbie.)

Comment: Watch out, before conducting the analysis, to take into account the order of the answers, if they were not randomly shuffled, as this can impact on the relative frequences, at least moderately: http://blogs.articulate.com/word-of-mouth/5-tips-for-working-with-multiple-choice-questions-in-quizmaker-09/

Comment: I looked at the frequencies and thought that the P-value will be _tiny_ but that's based on some experience and even with experience you can be (very) wrong on occasion, naturally.  But presumably you have other questions too. I don't know your reporting context but reporting such P-values does no harm. The null hypothesis is a reasonable reference case.

Comment: @Giuseppe. You've hit on a very important point for me, which I was going to ask about in a separate thread, but since you've raised it ... The first three options are randomised, but the fourth is "Other (please specify)" and always appears at the end. I fully understand that it's therefore strictly incorrect to expect it to be selected the same number of times as the others: partly because it always appears last and partly because it requests (though doesn't require) further input. Have you any idea whether there are conventions for weighting this sort of option differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chi-squared test where your null hypothesis is that they were chosen at random i.e. A=B=C=D and the alternative hypothesis is that the mean for at least one of the answers is not equal to the others.

The test statistic is 
$$T=\sum_i^N \frac{(observed_i-expected_i)^2}{expected_i}$$

Here $T$ follows approximately a chi-squared distribution. In the above formula, if everyone guessed you would expect each answer to get selected 50 times so that would be the "expected" value for each.

Comment: See also comments above. Although I've edited for expression, the reference to a _mean_ should be to a _frequency_ or _count_. As this is a statistical point I've not edited it.